# How come I suddenly don't have any audio?

Tags: debian, gnome, audio, troubleshooting

Just a few minutes ago my sound was working, and then it stopped! I suspect it was caused by me checking out some video editors. How do I go about troubleshooting this?

What I've so far tried:

- I ran `lsof | grep audio` and `lsof | grep delete` to see if there's any process locking the audio path(?), but nothing looks suspect.
- VLC and MPlayer are affected, while [Quod Libet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) (GStreamer) isn't.

[**update**] Strange one. I don't know if it has anything to do with Quod Libet, but I noticed that after closing (and reopening) it, the problem seemed to disappear. Note that I haven't logged out yet.

Comment: maybe try deleting weird settings in your home?

Comment: @phu I didn't change any settings.

Comment: and what did you expect to see with `lsof | grep delete`?

Comment: @alex I was checking if there was some old proces still holding onto the audio device, blocking others from accessing it.

Comment: and what that 'delete' thing has to do with that?

Comment: @alex I unistalled some programs, so was checking if they were still alive. Have you played with `lsof` before? When a process is still alive, and the file gets deleted, it's flagged as "deleted".

Comment: oh, didn't know that.  that might make sense

Answer (score 1):

You might try logging out of your desktop and logging back in.  Sometimes this is enough to kill any locks, delete tmp files, reset any other configuration gizmos that might have gotten left by a mis-behaving application.  You might also try poking through the Sound Preferences configuration for the hardware selections and make sure that your selected output hardware looks correct.

Knowing which distro you're using might help in getting more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of pulseaudio. Try killing it and rerunning the application.

Comment: This could be it, because I installed it as well. But then I didn't even stop it, and the problem went away.